# How can i add a widget fixed on the bottom left of my index page without removing a messenger chat icon on the opposite side?

Tags: html, css, indexing, embed, squarespace

Hello forgive me if im asking a stupid question, but im rather new to this and have been searching the internet for a few days for a answer and stumbled across this forum.

Im currently creating a website for a client (normally doing graphic design, and dabbling in this area for once) and im using squarespace. There are some codes that do not show up in the header/footer. I currently have the facebook messenger chat in the "code injection" and would like to keep that showing at the bottom right.

This is the website:

wwww.cryptocollective.trade

Ive managed to create two buttons on the side of the website that are fixed on the screen on all devices (above the messenger chat icon), but i would really like to add a widget to the bottom left corner of all pages including the cover.

This is the current code i have for a widget i would like to add to the bottom left corner

Cryptocurrency Prices by Coinlib

The way i got the two buttons to work was by first putting the code into "Code Injection" then adding some more code into CSS.

So is there any way i can do the same thing for the above code to add this widget fixed on the bottom left of my page without having to remove the messenger chat?

if anyone can point me in the right direction of a tutorial etc would be greateful

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You would use CSS to put the code in the bottom left.

```
.example {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
```

This would be my guess seeing that the "code" you mentioned is not attached in your question above.